# Regex to format files output

Tags: linux, awk, sed, regular-expression, text-formatting

I have file which has the following contents:

```
   foo-6-25.example.com:
         1  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 49)
    --
    foo-5-4.example.com:
         1  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 19)
    --
    foo-8-28.example.com:
         1  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 43)
    --
    foo-9-7.example.com:
         1  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 91)
    --
    foo-5-19.idmz.example.com:
         1  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 19)
    --
    foo-7-3.example.com:
         1  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 20)
```

I want to format it in the following way: servername and then its FAN speed which is inside `()` bracket

```
foo-6-25.example.com: ( 49)
foo-5-4.example.com:  ( 19)
```

Not sure how to use that using awk or any other tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` solution

```
$ awk '/:/{d=$1}/Speed/{printf"%-28s%s\n",d,substr($0,length($0)-4)}' file
foo-6-25.example.com:       ( 49)
foo-5-4.example.com:        ( 19)
foo-8-28.example.com:       ( 43)
foo-9-7.example.com:        ( 91)
foo-5-19.idmz.example.com:  ( 19)
foo-7-3.example.com:        ( 20)
$
```

`awk` + `column` solution

Aligns the columns dynamically.

```
$ awk '/:/{d=$1}/Speed/{print d,substr($0,length($0)-4)}' file|column -to' '
foo-6-25.example.com:       ( 49)
foo-5-4.example.com:        ( 19)
foo-8-28.example.com:       ( 43)
foo-9-7.example.com:        ( 91)
foo-5-19.idmz.example.com:  ( 19)
foo-7-3.example.com:        ( 20)
$
```

Comment: you are just awesome!!!

Comment: I like your `aws + column` solution but in output i am seeing `foo-8-1.example.com:       (          49)`  how do i reduce this space in ` ( look like tab space 49)` ?

Comment: `column: illegal option -- o`  :(

Comment: nevermid my bad, i was on `MacBookPro` after moving my file on Linux it seems looking good

Comment: Damn!!! it you are the beast in `awk`  take a bow!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -e '/--/d;N;s/\n/ /;s/[[:blank:]]\+//;s/[[:blank:]]\+[^(]\+/, /' file | column -ts ','
foo-6-25.example.com:        ( 49)
foo-5-4.example.com:         ( 19)
foo-8-28.example.com:        ( 43)
foo-9-7.example.com:         ( 91)
foo-5-19.idmz.example.com:   ( 19)
foo-7-3.example.com:         ( 20)
```

If you don't want any spacing/alignment of the 2nd column you can omit the `column` command:

```
$ sed -e '/--/d;N;s/\n/ /;s/[[:blank:]]\+//;s/[[:blank:]]\+[^(]\+/ /' file
foo-6-25.example.com: ( 49)
foo-5-4.example.com: ( 19)
foo-8-28.example.com: ( 43)
foo-9-7.example.com: ( 91)
foo-5-19.idmz.example.com: ( 19)
foo-7-3.example.com: ( 20)
```

If you're dealing with GNU `sed` you can reduce it further:

```
$ sed -e '/--/d;N;s/\n/ /;s/[ ]\+//;s/[ ]\+[^(]\+/ /' file
```

Comment: I have tired your solution but its printing everything in single like like `foo-010101-5-4.example.com:      1  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 19)`

Comment: I suspect your output isn't just spaces as you're showing in the example data, is it?

Comment: my file is correct and i am replacing `file` with my filename.txt

Comment: I showed this style of example b/c unlike the `awk` you can more easily add/remove portions of this solution to see how it's working. Each `/../;` block in the `sed` is doing something specific, you can take them all out and then add them back in 1 at a time to see how they work and work towards you solution rather than have to have a lot of knowledge about awk.

Answer (score 1):

```
% perl -ne 'print(($_ .= <>) =~ s/\n.*\(/ (/r) if /:/' input.file
```

outputs:

```
foo-6-25.example.com: ( 49)
foo-5-4.example.com: ( 19)
foo-8-28.example.com: ( 43)
foo-9-7.example.com: ( 91)
foo-5-19.idmz.example.com: ( 19)
foo-7-3.example.com: ( 20)
```

explanation:

1. on a line comprising `:`, it appends the next line to the current record.
2. then deletes from the newline of the original line till the last `(` and replaces this with `(`  and prints the record.
3. Since `perl` was invoked with `-n`, records not affected are not printed.

`Sed` has a very compact way to write the same:

```
sed -ne '/:/N;s/\n.*(/ (/p' input.file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk in *paragraph mode*

```
awk -vRS='\n[ \t]*--' '
  match($0, /\( *[0-9]+\)/) {print $1, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}
' file
foo-6-25.example.com: ( 49)
foo-5-4.example.com: ( 19)
foo-8-28.example.com: ( 43)
foo-9-7.example.com: ( 91)
foo-5-19.idmz.example.com: ( 19)
foo-7-3.example.com: ( 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
< file perl -pe 's/\n//g;s/(foo)/\n$1/g' | perl -pe 's/:.*\(/: (/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -nE '/:/{N;s/^[[:space:]]+//; s/:[^(]+/: /p;}' file
foo-6-25.example.com: ( 49)
foo-5-4.example.com: ( 19)
foo-8-28.example.com: ( 43)
foo-9-7.example.com: ( 91)
foo-5-19.idmz.example.com: ( 19)
foo-7-3.example.com: ( 20)
```

If there are no initial spaces or tabs on each line, then just

```
sed -nE '/:/{N;s/:[^(]+/: /p;}' file
```

The (first) `sed` script annotated (assumes `-E` and `-n`):

```
/:/{                    # this line contains a host name
    N;                  # append the next line from the input
    s/^[[:space:]]+//;  # remove the initial spaces or tabs
    s/:[^(]+/: /p;      # remove the bit between the ":" and "(" and print
}
```